# Creating a Sentiment dictionary from scratch

Tags: machine-learning, text-classification, sentiment-analysis, topic-model

I am analyzing Arabic textual data from a social media forum discussing economic issues such as labor unions. I am using a [package](http://mazajak.inf.ed.ac.uk:8000/) that classifies as negative, positive, or neutral.
For instance, the first column is the post is the input, while the second is the sentiment analysis of the text:

```
Post                                                      Sentiment         
1-"Let's organize a strike to demand higher wages"        Negative 

2-"The whole system needs to be revamped, 
not enough to simply unionize and go on a strike"         Negative
```

However, I would like to also know whether a post that is classified as negative contains: political_demands, economic_demands, and/or calls for collective_action. For example, based on the two posts above, my dataset would have three additional columns:

```
Post                                                      Sentiment  Economic_demands  Political_Demands collective_action
1-"Let's organize a strike to demand higher wages"        Negative    Yes               No                Yes                    
 
2-"The whole system needs to be revamped,                                  
not enough to simply unionize and go on a strike"         Negative    No               Yes                Yes
```

Therefore, I need to create a dictionary that categorizes posts classified as having a  negative sentiment into several groups: political_demands, economic_demands, and/or calls for collective_action. I am not sure whether it makes more sense to create a dictionary based on words or phrases/topics in the dataset.

Following the method used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65616674/how-to-label-text-either-positive-or-negative-based-on-words-in-a-dictionary-in), I am creating a dataset called "Dictionary" where I classify words as positive or negative, then merging it with my dataset on social media posts, is this an efficient classification approach?

```
Raw_data_on_posts %>% mutate(p_count = str_count(post, str_c(Dictionary$positive, collapse = '|')), 
                 n_count = str_count(post, str_c(Dictionary$negative, collapse = '|'))) %>% 
           mutate(label = case_when(p_count > n_count ~ 'positive',
                                    p_count < n_count ~ 'negative',
                                    TRUE ~ 'neutral')) %>% select(post, label)
```

Comment: The standard approach would be to train a classification model instead of creating a custom dictionary. Is there a reason why you want to do it this way?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, because I am analyzing Arabic text and to my knowledge, there are no readily available sentiment analysis packages in R/Python.

Comment: Ok but classification can be done without sentiment analysis using a labelled training set. For the 3 categories it looks more appropriate at first sight.

Comment: Thanks, mind elaborating further. Check my updated question to see if the approach makes sense.